# Joda time getting right time from dateTime

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, jodatime

I have this simple code:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm yyyy-MM-dd");

    DateTime dateTime = formatter.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("America/New_York")).parseDateTime("08:30 2015-06-01");
    DateTime dateTime2 = formatter.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("America/New_York")).parseDateTime("08:30 2015-12-01");
```

these are leap times. when I hit toString method, I got something like this:

```
2015-06-01T08:30:00.000-04:00
2015-12-01T08:30:00.000-05:00
```

which is correct, we can see UTC time - offset. But when I call getHourOfDay, I got 8 and not 4/3 as expected. What am I doing wrong? Please, share some advices here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, from the Javadoc for `DateTimeFormatter#withZone()`:

> Returns a new formatter that will use the specified zone in preference to the zone of the printed object, or default zone on a parse.

So, you told the formatter to use the specific timezone on parsing AND output, and the input you gave it did NOT contain a timezone, so this is the expected result.  In essence you said:

1. Here's a date string without timezone, parse it assuming America/New_York
2. Convert the date back to String, in the timezone America/New_York

This is what it did.

Comment: that's great. so considering I have UTC time and I need ET(new york) time, I need to parse it without any zone and then print it like this: 
System.out.println(dateTime.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("America/New_York")).getHourOfDay()); ?

Comment: If the input is UTC, then the string must contain the timezone or you must tell the system it's UTC explicitly.